# My listView do not display my data

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

my list view don't display the data binded to it
askind for help i gave here the exemple for displaying only one element
i want to know where is the problem with my code
pleese help me :(

here is my code:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MovieData}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=MovieId}" Header="Movie Id" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Title}" Header="Title" />
                    <!-- Can Bind to complex subclass -->
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Movie(s)">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MovieImage}">
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    </ItemsControl>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <!-- Binding with data triggers -->

                    <!-- Simple binding -->
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Recommendation}" Header="Recommendations" />

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

and here is my class Movie:

```
public class Movie
    {
        public int MovieId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public BitmapImage MovieImage { get; set; }
        public string Recommendation { get; set; }
        public Movie() { }

        public void CreateMovie(int i, string T , string R)
        {
            MovieId = i;
            Title = T;
            Recommendation = R;
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();
            bi.UriSource = new        Uri(@"http://pierre.chachatelier.fr/programmation/images/mozodojo-original-image.jpg");
            bi.EndInit();
            MovieImage = bi;


        }

    }
```

here i just add one element for test:

```
 public List<Movie> MovieData= new List<Movie>();
 Movie m = new Movie();
 m.CreateMovie(5, "d", "s");
 MovieData.Add(m);
```

Comment: I think your MovieData list has to be an ObservableCollection, not a List<T> in order to get notified when objects are added to it.

Comment: would you explain more ?

Comment: see http://immersivenick.wordpress.com/2012/02/04/wpf-short-observablecollection-inotifypropertychanged-2/ or google ObservableCollection

Comment: i don't see what you mean, my project has a list of movies brought from my database, so my list wont change and all i have is displaying it on my listview , i dont see the relation with your indication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a [View Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/magazine/dd419663.aspx) approach in your code behind:

```
public class MovieViewModel
{
   public ObservableCollection<Movie> MovieData { get; set; }

   public MovieViewModel()
   {
      //the code you post
      MovieData = new ObservableCollection<Movie>();
      Movie m = new Movie();
      m.CreateMovie(5, "d", "s");
      MovieData.Add(m);
   }
}
```

and in your window constructor:

```
private MovieViewModel vm;
public MyWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   vm = new MovieViewModel();
   this.DataContext = vm;
}
```

**EDIT**: I've just read your comment. If your list will never change and it's only loaded from a DB, you can ignore my answer above and:

- remove `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MovieData}"` from the ListView in
  your XAML
- give a name to to Listview `Name="movieListView"`

change your code to the following:

```
List<Movie> MovieData= new List<Movie>();
Movie m = new Movie();
m.CreateMovie(5, "d", "s");
MovieData.Add(m);
movieListView.ItemsSource = MovieData;
```

Comment: thanks the listview dsplayed data but not the image, any indication pleese

Comment: why did you need an ItemControl for your image? Using  <Image Source="{Binding MovieImage}" /> for example and you'll see the image.

Comment: the same problem, data displayed without the image, is there a possibility that the problem with the BitmapImage

Comment: sorry for wasting your time :), i used ItemControl for the image because without it the columne of the image display the uri (only text)

Comment: Putting the <Image Source="{Binding MovieImage}" /> inside your StackPanel into the CellTemplate show you the uri text? Really strange, I see the image, but I maybe built up a simpler test app!

Comment: can you send me your test app

Comment: thanks, my problem was that i did not remove "path=", really thanks and sorry for wasting your time :)